# Laravel check livewire component existence

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

I want to check if a livewire component exists before rendering.
 My program has modules and each client has some of those modules enabled. I can get the list of modules a client has with `$client->getModules()`.
Each module can implement livewire components to enhance functions of the program. I want to render those components if they exist in the correct section of the program. 
For example in the user creation view, I would have this:

```
@foreach($client->getModules() as $module)
    if( component_exists( $module . '::users.create' ) )
        @livewire( $module . '::users.create' )
    endif;
@endforeach
```

If the module implements something related to the user creation, it will have the livewire component `users.create`, but not all modules will enhance user creation. 
I need to assert the existence of the component before rendering it. 
I was wondering if there is something like `component_exists( Component::class )`, otherwise, I would love to see if someone could give me a hint in how to create it as a helper function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can take advantage of `LivewireComponentsFinder` class to check if component is in manifest :

```php
app(LivewireComponentsFinder::class)->getManifest();
```

If you want to create a helper, I created [laravel-helpers](https://github.com/wearedevtical/laravel-helpers). So, you can create a helper like this:

```
function component_exists($class)
{
    $manifest = app(\Livewire\LivewireComponentsFinder::class)->getManifest();

    return (bool) array_search($class, $manifest);
}
```

Comment: Your answer is correct, and it worked fine, but I've decided to go with a simple PHP function to do the check return class_exists( $modules_path . $module . $livewire_path . $class );

Comment: Besides the getManifest method on the LivewireComponentsFinder, there is also a find($alias) method which does what the second part of the answer does...
So easier:  app(LivewireComponentsFinder::class)->find($class);

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check is **Livewire Component** registered/exists, in **Livewire 3** there is an another way. You have to pass a `classname` and if alias returned means your component is registered, also `alias` shows path to a class

```
<?php
use Livewire\Mechanisms\ComponentRegistry;
echo app(ComponentRegistry::class)->getName(\Your\Component::class); //returns your.component
```